# bash rename files issue?

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file

I know nothing about Linux commands o bash scripts so help me please. 
I have a lot of file in different directories i want to rename all those files from "name" to "name.xml" using bash file is it possible to do that? I just find usefulness codes on the internet like this:

```
shopt -s globstar # enable ** globstar/recursivity
for i in **/*.txt; do
echo "$i" "${i/%.txt}.xml";
done
```

it does not even work.

Comment: "Does not even work" is not very useful. What is the output? How did you run it?

Comment: it just shows **/*.txt **/*.xml for one time after i use "bash file.sh"

Comment: Is that verbatim? Even if the match failed, it should be `**/.txt` (note two asterisks) and `**/*.xml`.

Comment: The Bash script you quote look only for .txt files. Note that to use globstar, you need bash >=4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explanation

Move/rename all files –whatever the extension is– in current directory and below from `name` to `name.xml`. You should test using `echo` before running the real script.

```
shopt -s globstar # enable ** globstar/recursivity
for i in **; do # **/*.txt will look only for .txt files
    [[ -d "$i" ]] && continue # skip directories
    echo "$i" "$i.xml"; # replace 'echo' by 'mv' when validated
    #echo "$i" "${i/%.txt}.xml"; # replace .txt by .xml
done
```

Comment: This isn't the best way to go as it would echo directories as directory.xml as well. See my answer

Comment: it works perfectly like a charm thank you but if i want to edit it to replace just .txt files,how??

Comment: see comment on the for loop line and commented echo

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose comes in handy the `prename` utility which is installed by default on many Linux distributions, usually it is distributed with the Perl package. You can use it like this:

```
find . -iname '*.txt' -exec prename 's/.txt/.xml/' {} \;
```

or this much faster alternative:

```
find . -iname '*.txt' | xargs prename 's/.txt/.xml/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing `*/.txt */.xml` means effectively there are **no** files matching the given pattern, as by default bash will use verbatim `*` if no matches are found.

To prevent this issue you'd have to additionally set `shopt -s nullglob` to have bash just return nothing when there is no match at all.

After verifying the echoed lines look somewhat reasonable you'll have to replace

```
echo "$i" "${i/%.txt}.xml"
```

with

```
mv "$i" "${i/%.txt}.xml"
```

to rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY=/your/base/dir/here
for i in `find $DIRECTORY -type d -exec find {} -type f  -name \*.txt\;`;
do mv $i $i.xml
done
```